# c++ visual studio10 After compiling, how do i make it so that it displays the calculation time

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, time

I dont know how you call it.. After you compile with visual studio10, black screen pops up and displays the results.

I have noticed on youtube videos that on their screen, it also displays how long it took to calculate.(not compiling time)

Im pretty sure the answer is out there but I dont know the keywords for searching..

Comment: http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/ctime/ is the standard library functions for manipulating time. The simple approach to to get the time when your program starts (using `time`), then when your program ends (again using `time`), subtract the first from the second (using `difftime`) and display the result.

Comment: Use std::chrono.  There's a high resolution timer in there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a little stopwatch class I use to time things.  Accuracy is ... well ... it gets better the more work you're doing, put it that way.

```
    #include <sstream>
    #include <chrono>

    class Stopwatch final
    {
    public:

        Stopwatch()
        {
            Reset();
        }

        void Reset()
        {
            MyCurrentTime = MyClock.now();
        }

        double Elapsed() const
        {
            auto elapsed = std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::duration<double>>(MyClock.now() - MyCurrentTime);

            return elapsed.count();
        }

        int ms() const
        {
            return static_cast<int>(0.5 + Elapsed() * 1000);
        }

        std::string ToMilliseconds() const
        {
            auto o = std::ostringstream();

            o << ms();

            return o.str();
        }

        std::string ToSeconds(int precision) const
        {
            auto o = std::ostringstream();

            o.precision(precision);

            o << std::fixed << Elapsed();

            return o.str();
        }

    private:

        std::chrono::high_resolution_clock MyClock;
        std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::time_point MyCurrentTime;
    };
```

Answer (score 0):

A small example:

[`omp_get_wtime`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x721b5yk.aspx)

```
#include <omp.h>

int main(void)
{
    double dStart = omp_get_wtime();

    Calculations();

    double dEnd = omp_get_wtime();

    std::cout << "Calculation took: " << dEnd - dStart << " sec." std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```